# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I am trying to use the jQueryUI dialog in an MVC3 application but having an issue with it.
The dialog I have is loading a partial view into it where the user will either edit or create a new item. This works fine but if I try to save or update the item, or if I try to close it I get the message in the title.

I have added all of the required .js files but still getting the error. I have also used firebug but still can't find why error is happening.

**HTML**

```
<span class="EditLink ButtonLink" addressId="@addr.Id">Modify this Address</span>
<div id="popup"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = 0;

    //define config object
    var dialogOpts = {
        title: "Edit item",
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        open: function () {
            $("#popup").load("/partialviewtoload/" + id);
        },
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    };

    $("#popup").dialog(dialogOpts);    //end dialog

    $('.EditLink').click(function() {
        id = $(this).attr("itemId");
        $("#popup").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

issue was that I was referencing "jquery-1.5.1.min.js" twice. Once in the _Layout.cshtml and also in the partial view I was loading. . Removed the reference in the partial view and got it sorted.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that browser have not loaded jQueryUI, ensure that it is in your DOM

Comment: It has loaded jqueryui as I can see it using firebug. Also, the dialog loads the first time no problem. The issue is trying to close it using the $(this).dialog('close') and also reopening it.

Comment: So, I think that `$(this)` is not pointing to an element containing dialog object. Before `$(this).dialog('close')` test `$(this)` by `console.log(this)`

Comment: OK, the console shows the div "popup". but straight after that i get the error again.

Comment: I have narrowed the cause of the issue. It only happens when I load the partial view into the dialog. If I don't load the partial view I can close and reopen no problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that

> you should include first grid.locale-en.js and then jquery.jqGrid.min.js.