# dialog jquery has no method when loading modal window

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a url in modal window but i am getting the following error message: Uncaught  TypeError: Object [object object] has no method 'dialog'. Below is my code.

```
function()
{
   var id = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow'), 
  data={};
  if(id) 
  {
       data = {assetID:id};
  }
   else 
  {
     alert('Please select a row to edit');
     return;
  } 
   var ajaxDialog = $('<div id="ajax-Dialog" style="display:hidden" title="New Work Order"></div>').appendTo('body');
   ajaxDialog.load('forms/mwoForm.php',
       data,
       function(response, status)
       {
           ajaxDialog.dialog(
           {
               width: 'auto',
               modal:true,
               open: function(ev, ui)
               {
                  $(".ui-dialog").css('font-size','0.9em');
               },
               close: function(e,ui) 
               {
                   ajaxDialog.remove();
               }
           });
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: You are missing jQueryui.js most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue a couple of times and it is usually linked to referencing jQuery twice.

This thread can give more explanation:
Have you seen this solution:
[Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786104/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-dialog)

Edit:
Dialog is a widget and does need to be included:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

or if you want to load the jQuery UI:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Can't see all of your code, but make sure that it has been included.

Comment: here is the scripts being loaded
<head>
  <title>Maintenance Work Order System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

Comment: When i click on the button the url loads under neath of grid instead of in a modal window

Comment: its already part of my code....I tried to just do a simple JQForm and couldnt get it to work either.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Maintenance Work Order System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>