# Jquery Ui Dialog Does not open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Ive got a ASP.NET page that has a link that opens a dialog window "edit appointment", which works fine

```
function editAppointment(event) {
        $("#editAppointment")
            .load("/Schedule/Edit/" + event.id,
                function() {
                $("#editAppointment").dialog('open');

                });

    }
function loadClient(clientId) {
            alert('hi');
            $("#clientEditForm")
               .load("/Client/Edit/", function() {
                   $("#clientEditForm").dialog('open');
               });
        }
```

Within the page "/Schedule/Edit/" has a link to open the dialog "loadClient"

The function is called ok, but does not show another dialog window
it use to work with an older version of jquery ui/jquery, now using the latest versions!, all I get is a javascript error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' Schedule:346
(anonymous function) Schedule:346
b.extend.each jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4
b.fn.b.each jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4
(anonymous function) jquery.1.9.1.min.js:19
c jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4
p.fireWith jquery.1.9.1.min.js:4
k jquery.1.9.1.min.js:19
r
```

Comment: you might want to step through the js in chrome or firebug and see what is being selected by $("#clientEditForm")

Comment: renamed function, now get "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'"

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not finding the #clientEditForm element. Could it be that the /Client/Edit/ page is not loading properly? Based on your loadClient method, I assume you may actually want to load /Client/Edit/:clientId.

Comment: Try just calling $("#clientEditForm").dialog() without the 'open' method.

Comment: no change, call looks like this function loadClientWindow(clientId) {
        console.log('Start');
        $("#clientAppointmentEditForm")
           .load("/Client/Edit/" + clientId, function() {
               
               $("#clientAppointmentEditForm").dialog();
               console.log('End');
           });
    }

Comment: Make sure you are not loading jQuery twice. See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786104/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-object-has-no-method-dialog

Comment: Nope, view does not contain any references to jquey